# Trying to install latest python3

Tags: python-3.x

Hi guys I am following a web document how to install the latest version of python3 from deadsnake. After the installation I need to remove the symlink from python3 and recreate it to new python3 install.

```
rm /usr/bin/python3

ln -s python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```

But now i want to install ansible with `pip3 install ansible` i get this error:

> File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in 
> from pip import main   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 22, in 
> from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 73, in
>
> vendored("pkg_resources")   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 33, in
> vendored

Comment: Some extra info i did a tree /usr/bin/python3.10 and i got this.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Comment: Removing anything from `/usr/bin` is Asking For Trouble. What else did you do besides create the symbolic link? Update your question to give more insight into how you go to the point of having to remove `/usr/bin/python3`.